# idn2 works differently from bash script and command line

Tags: dns, ping

I have the following command `ping -qc 1 $(idn2 правительство.рф)` in a bash script file `ping.sh`.

When I run the script as `$ bash -x ./ping.sh` I get:

```
++ idn2 правительcтво.рф
+ ping -qc 1 xn--c-7sbgbnrw0abkzd2k.xn--p1ai
ping: unknown host xn--c-7sbgbnrw0abkzd2k.xn--p1ai
+ exit
```

with `idn2` result of `xn--c-7sbgbnrw0abkzd2k.xn--p1ai`

But when I type the command `$ ping -qc 1 $(idn2 правительство.рф)` in my terminal bash command line, I get another result:

```
PING xn--80aealotwbjpid2k.xn--p1ai (95.173.135.62) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- xn--80aealotwbjpid2k.xn--p1ai ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

with `idn2` result of `xn--80aealotwbjpid2k.xn--p1ai`.

What's this?

Comment: Is it `президент.рф` or `правительство.рф`?

Comment: It is `правительство.рф`. Sorry, I made a typo in the first sentence. I have edited my question to fix it. I have checked everything one more time. A still have the problem.

Comment: I suspect there's some issue with the way `bash` processes multibyte characters when reading from a script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, make sure you type international domain names with the right keyboard layout, and do not fix international domain names spelling with a wrong keyboard layout.

I have rewritten `правительство.рф` string in my script by hand, than I tested the script and the problem is gone. I was lucky that I have added the script in a git repo. So I `git diff`, and git shown me that there was a diff in `правительство.рф`. Then I `git difftool` with `vimdiff` set up as difftool and realized that I had ASCII `c` letter in `правительство.рф` instead of russian `c`. That was the problem.